# How to take value from one sheet and use it a formula in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I apologize, I know the title could be better but I am not sure how to exactly word what I am trying to do here.

So I have two sheets, one sheet that sums up daily expenses. There is a drop-down bar that lets you change the date. The second sheet has a list of days in the month. I am trying to match the date from sheet 1 to the date in sheet 2 and take the daily expenses from sheet 1 and put them in the corresponding date in sheet 2. I then want to sum up all the expenses in sheet 2 for a monthly total. If that was a confusing explanation, I apologize. This overall is a first for me. Here are some pictures if it helps everyone understand. I tried using the following formula in an attempt to force sheet 2 to keep the sum of a day if I change the date in sheet 1. It works but then I am unable to do a monthly sum in sheet 2. For some reason, excel doesn't seem to like the formula

```
=IF(A2='Daily Expenses 2021'!D1,'Daily Expenses 2021'!B10,0)
```

The picture may seem like it is summing up the monthly expenses fine but it doesn't. I apologize, it was the best picture I could get. The more I tried to fix the formula more messed up things got

[image]
[image]

Here is the document I am working with [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhcVeoMqgqFfgQZvqIHMR_cMRhFV?e=yzziUy)

Comment: This is a very easy problem to solve, upload your files instead of pictures.

Comment: @Can.U I added a link to the document at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 0):

**The formulas of the Daily Expenses 2021 and Monthly Expenses 2021 tables will cause circular references.** It is recommended to manually enter daily data in the Monthly Expenses 2021 worksheet, and the Daily Expenses 2021 worksheet can use the drop-down menu to query. If you need to select a date in Daily Expenses 2021, and the recorded amount is automatically generated in the worksheet Monthly Expenses 2021, then only VBA can meet the conditions.

---

If the worksheet Daily Expenses 2021 is used for query, then the formulas in the worksheet Monthly Expenses 2021 must be cleared.
Total formula

```
=SUMIF('Monthly Expenses 2021'!A:AH,D1,'Monthly Expenses 2021'!B1)
```

---

Worksheet 'Yearly Expenses 2021' recommends using a formula, B2 pull down.

```
=OFFSET('Monthly Expenses 2021'!A$1,32,ROW(A1)*3-2)
```

---

*If you need code help, my leisure to add.*